# ngsw-worker.js file not retrieved on subsequent HTTP requests

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

So I have followed all the steps in this tutorial by Angular in their documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#getting-started-with-service-workers

When I build the Angular project for the first time, run it in an incognito Chrome browser, my logs say that the `ngsw-worker.js` was retrieved successfully (GET) with `http-server`.

When I remove the service worker in the dev tools, open up a new incognito tab (or close the browser and open a new incognito window), there is no `ngsw-worker.js` retrieved from the `http-server`, therefore, no service worker is in the browser.

Why is this? This has been bugging me for ages. The only way to retrieve the new service worker is to rebuild the project with `ng build --prod`. And even then, it can be quite inconsistent.

Additional info:

- I run my local server with `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<project-name>`
- Angular version: 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The service worker is broken/inconsistent in some versions of Angular 7.

[See the author's post in this GitHub issue for a temporary workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13351)